# Extract String from another String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following String example :

```
test_client_guide..mydomain.fr.global.com=198787879898977979
```

I would like to extract in a variable the following String :

```
.mydomain.fr.global.com
```

In fact, i would like to **get the String which is between the first "." and the "=" character.**

How can i do that ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: You can use a regular expression, or you can use `indexOf` to find the positions of the characters and then use `substr` to extract the substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var myString = "test_client_guide..mydomain.fr.global.com=198787879898977979";
    var str=myString.substring(myString.indexOf (".")+1,myString.indexOf("="));
    alert(str);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for that.

```
var string = 'test_client_guide..mydomain.fr.global.com=198787879898977979';
alert(string.replace(/^.*?\.(.+?)=.*$/, '$1'));
```

This would replace the following pattern:

- `^` - start of the string
- `.*?\.` - zero or more characters until the first `.`
- `(.+?)=` - one or more characters until the first `=` (captured as `$1`)
- `.*$` - zero or more characters until the end of the string

with:

- `$1` - the capture above

Comment: No need to match `^.*` and `.*$` - simply `/\.(.+?)=/`

Comment: @thg435, sure, but I'm using `replace()` to remove everything that's outside the first group.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex, something like:

```
^.*?\.(.*)=
```

Would give you the piece you wanted in the first capture group.

See: http://rubular.com/r/WDIO27zriw

`^`: start of string

`.*?`: Match any character, non-greedy (the `?` is key to making it not greedy)

`\.`: Match the first `.` - note it has to be escaped because `.` is a character class in regex (see the previous part)

`(.*)`: Match any character (`.`) and put it in a capture group (the - `()`)

`=`: Match the `=`

Comment: You should make the `.*` lazy by making it `.*?`, so that it will take the first occurrence of that character, instead of the last occurrence. There'd be a difference in the result if you'd get to handle strings such as "foo..bar.baz=1337&quux=quok", since it'll match everything until the last equals sign.

Comment: @joeytje50: True, but the test string only has one `=` and it's not clear in the case of more than one `=` if the OP would want the first or the last (probably the first).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `substr` and `indexOf`:

```
var exampleString = "test_client_guide..mydomain.fr.global.com=198787879898977979";
var firstdot = exampleString.indexOf('.')+1;
var firsteq = exampleString.indexOf('=', firstdot);
exampleString = exampleString.substring(firstdot, firsteq);
//exampleString now contains the contents ".mydomain.fr.global.com"
```

This gets your string from *after* the first period until the first equals sign after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression

```
 ^.*?(\..*)=
```

Edit to make numbered group since Javascript doesn't support named groups

Answer (score 0):

this may be helpful

```
var s="test_client_guide..mydomain.fr.global.com=198787879898977979";
var _s=s.substring(s.indexOf("mydomain."),s.length);
_s=_s.substring(_s.indexOf("="),0)
console.log(_s)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/semir/KFL2W/1/)